# Upload photo with facebook api from Android, look like success but nothing change in my facebook

Tags: android, facebook, api, upload, photo

First, thanks for you reading.
Here is my code

```
public void uploadPicture(String token, String message, File imageFile) throws ParseException, IOException {
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos");

MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();

mpEntity.addPart(Facebook.TOKEN, new StringBody(token));
mpEntity.addPart("source", new FileBody(imageFile, "image/png"));
mpEntity.addPart("message", new StringBody(message));
httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);

// DEBUG
Log.v(CLASS_NAME, "executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

// DEBUG
Log.v(CLASS_NAME, "getStatusLine " + response.getStatusLine());
if (resEntity != null) {
Log.v(CLASS_NAME, EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
} // end if

if (resEntity != null) {
resEntity.consumeContent();
} // end if

httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```

DDMS show the response:

```
executing request POST https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos HTTP/1.1
getStatusLine HTTP/1.1 200 OK
{"id":"113353398770816″}
```

so, it should complete finished. but nothing change in my facebook.
can anyone tell me what i did wrong?

thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to wait a little. I've seen that uploaded picture appeared after some time.